# PowerShell Check for .EXE in $env:Path

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, logic

**SOLVED**
*Thanks to Mathias R. Jessen's suggestion.*

Good Afternoon,
I'm working on a script to check for installed software and pull their version info if installed. It works in its base form of just pulling the info but it will throw an error for anything that isn't installed. I'm trying to incorporate some logic into it so that it will just throw that the specific software isn't installed instead of the error message. Below is the code I'm trying to use. The paths to all the software is added to the $env:Path through this script.

**EDITED CODE**
Was solved by changing `Test-Path` to `Get-Command` and adding `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to both `Get-Command` sections.

```
$Env:Path += ";C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\"
$Env:Path += ";C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Remote Console\"
$Env:Path += ";C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\esxcli\"
$Env:Path += ";C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware OVF Tool\"
$Env:Path += ";C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\"
$Env:Path += ";C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\"

$apps = @("ovftool","vmrc","vmware","msedge","firefox")

ForEach ($app in $apps) {
    If(Get-Command $app -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
        (Get-Command $app -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).FileVersionInfo|Select-Object ProductName, ProductVersion |Format-Table -AutoSize
    }else{
        Write-Output "$app is not installed"
    }
}
```

Comment: Try replacing `if(Test-Path $app)` with `if(Get-Command $app)`

Comment: This worked. I just had to add ``-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`` to it as well to silence the error

Answer (score 0):

You can try with GetExtenion

```
 if ([IO.Path]::GetExtension($app) -eq ".exe") 
    {
        # file has .exe extension
    }
```

Comment: When I try that, it outputs back that nothing is installed